# Camel FTP Cannot list directory with 'File not found' pre-pending additional '/' in front of directory automatically

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I am trying to poll file from a Windows Server. SFTP hosted using IP Switch / WS_FTP. 
[image: User Permissions]

I need to poll files form a dynamic folder based on a specific date, so I have provided the parent directory in endpoint URI, enabled recursive flag and add filterDirectory accordingly. But It is not able to poll from the directory, it says file not found for that directory. It is trying with an addition '/' while listing `listFor(/XXXX)`

**Endpoint URI**

```
sftp://XXXX:22051?connectTimeout=90000&disconnect=true&filterDirectory=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D+starts+with+%27%24%7Bbean%3AdateofExchange%3Fmethod%3DforLoc%28%22MY%22%29%7D%27&flatten=true&include=.*IMG&knownHostsFile=C%3A%5Cprogram+files%5Cascertain%5CI2R-MystiQ-Engine%5Cknown_hosts&noop=true&password=xxxxxx&preferredAuthentications=password&reconnectDelay=30000&recursive=true&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0%2F5+*+*+*+%3F&stepwise=false&username=XXXX_ftpuser
```

**TRACE LOG**

```
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:03,389 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Polling directory: 
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:03,389 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations] - listFiles()
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:03,712 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Found 12 in directory: 
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:03,712 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=., longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 05:27 ., dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:03,712 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[.]
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:03,712 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=.., longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 03:04 .., dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:03,712 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[..]
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:03,728 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=20170526, longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 02:16 20170526, dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:04,413 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[20170526]
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:04,413 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=20181119, longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 05:24 20181119, dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:05,117 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[20181119]
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:05,117 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=20181121, longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 05:25 20181121, dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:05,837 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[20181121]
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:05,840 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=20181122, longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 05:26 20181122, dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:06,561 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[20181122]
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:06,563 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=20181123, longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 05:27 20181123, dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:07,258 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Polling sub directory: /20181123 from: sftp://XXXX:22051?connectTimeout=90000&disconnect=true&filterDirectory=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D+starts+with+%27%24%7Bbean%3AdateofExchange%3Fmethod%3DforLoc%28%22MY%22%29%7D%27&flatten=true&include=.*IMG&knownHostsFile=C%3A%5Cprogram+files%5Cascertain%5CI2R-MystiQ-Engine%5Cknown_hosts&noop=true&password=xxxxxx&preferredAuthentications=password&reconnectDelay=30000&recursive=true&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0%2F5+*+*+*+%3F&stepwise=false&username=XXXX_ftpuser
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:07,260 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - doPollDirectory from absolutePath: /20181123, dirName: 20181123
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:07,263 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Polling directory: /20181123
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:07,265 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations] - listFiles(/20181123)
DEBUG 2019-04-05T15:25:07,281 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Caught exception Cannot list directory: /20181123
TRACE 2019-04-05T15:25:07,297 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Not ignoring file error Cannot list directory: /20181123 for /20181123
DEBUG 2019-04-05T15:25:07,297 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Error occurred during poll directory:  due Cannot list directory: /20181123. Removing 0 files marked as in-progress.
WARN  2019-04-05T15:25:07,297 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFilePollingConsumerPollStrategy] - Trying to recover by force disconnecting from remote server and re-connecting at next poll: sftp://XXX@1XXXX:22051
DEBUG 2019-04-05T15:25:07,297 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Force disconnecting from: sftp://XXX@XXXX:22051
WARN  2019-04-05T15:25:07,297 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Consumer SftpConsumer[sftp://XXXX:22051?connectTimeout=90000&disconnect=true&filterDirectory=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D+starts+with+%27%24%7Bbean%3AdateofExchange%3Fmethod%3DforLoc%28%22MY%22%29%7D%27&flatten=true&include=.*IMG&knownHostsFile=C%3A%5Cprogram+files%5Cascertain%5CI2R-MystiQ-Engine%5Cknown_hosts&noop=true&password=xxxxxx&preferredAuthentications=password&reconnectDelay=30000&recursive=true&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0%2F5+*+*+*+%3F&stepwise=false&username=XXXX_ftpuser] failed polling endpoint: sftp://XXXX:22051?connectTimeout=90000&disconnect=true&filterDirectory=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D+starts+with+%27%24%7Bbean%3AdateofExchange%3Fmethod%3DforLoc%28%22MY%22%29%7D%27&flatten=true&include=.*IMG&knownHostsFile=C%3A%5Cprogram+files%5Cascertain%5CI2R-MystiQ-Engine%5Cknown_hosts&noop=true&password=xxxxxx&preferredAuthentications=password&reconnectDelay=30000&recursive=true&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0%2F5+*+*+*+%3F&stepwise=false&username=XXXX_ftpuser. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot list directory: /20181123]
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot list directory: /20181123
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.listFiles(SftpOperations.java:660) ~[camel-ftp-2.21.1.jar!/:2.21.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer.doPollDirectory(SftpConsumer.java:128) ~[camel-ftp-2.21.1.jar!/:2.21.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.doSafePollSubDirectory(RemoteFileConsumer.java:260) ~[camel-ftp-2.21.1.jar!/:2.21.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer.pollSubDirectory(SftpConsumer.java:96) ~[camel-ftp-2.21.1.jar!/:2.21.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer.doPollDirectory(SftpConsumer.java:178) ~[camel-ftp-2.21.1.jar!/:2.21.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer.pollDirectory(SftpConsumer.java:87) ~[camel-ftp-2.21.1.jar!/:2.21.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:124) ~[camel-core-2.21.1.jar!/:2.21.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174) [camel-core-2.21.1.jar!/:2.21.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101) [camel-core-2.21.1.jar!/:2.21.1]
    at org.apache.camel.pollconsumer.quartz2.QuartzScheduledPollConsumerJob.execute(QuartzScheduledPollConsumerJob.java:61) [camel-quartz2-2.21.1.jar!/:2.21.1]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) [quartz-2.3.0.jar!/:?]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) [quartz-2.3.0.jar!/:?]
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException: File not found: /20181123
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873) ~[jsch-0.1.54.jar!/:?]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2225) ~[jsch-0.1.54.jar!/:?]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2242) ~[jsch-0.1.54.jar!/:?]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1592) ~[jsch-0.1.54.jar!/:?]
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1553) ~[jsch-0.1.54.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.listFiles(SftpOperations.java:651) ~[camel-ftp-2.21.1.jar!/:2.21.1]
    ... 11 more
```

When I try to hardcode that folder along with endpint URI, it simply can list that directory and poll files. This time there is no '/' before the directory while listing `listFor(XXXX)`

**Endpoint URI**

```
sftp://XXXX:22051/20181123?connectTimeout=90000&disconnect=true&flatten=true&include=.*IMG&knownHostsFile=C%3A%5Cprogram+files%5Cascertain%5CI2R-MystiQ-Engine%5Cknown_hosts&noop=true&password=xxxxxx&preferredAuthentications=password&reconnectDelay=30000&recursive=true&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0%2F5+*+*+*+%3F&separator=Auto&stepwise=false&username=XXXX_ftpuser
```

**TRACE LOG**

```
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:00,009 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - prePollCheck on sftp://XXX@XXXX:22051
DEBUG 2019-04-05T18:40:00,009 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Not connected/logged in, connecting to: sftp://XXX@XXXX:22051
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:00,009 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations] - Session isn't connected, trying to recreate and connect.
DEBUG 2019-04-05T18:40:00,009 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations] - Using knownhosts file: C:\program files\ascertain\I2R-MystiQ-Engine\known_hosts
DEBUG 2019-04-05T18:40:00,009 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations] - Using known hosts information from file: C:\program files\ascertain\I2R-MystiQ-Engine\known_hosts
DEBUG 2019-04-05T18:40:00,025 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations] - Using StrickHostKeyChecking: no
DEBUG 2019-04-05T18:40:00,025 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations] - Using PreferredAuthentications: password
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:00,025 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations] - Connecting use connectTimeout: 90000 ...
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:00,465 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations] - Channel isn't connected, trying to recreate and connect.
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:00,465 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations] - Connecting use connectTimeout: 90000 ...
DEBUG 2019-04-05T18:40:01,215 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations] - Connected to sftp://XXX@XXXX:22051
DEBUG 2019-04-05T18:40:01,215 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Connected and logged in to: sftp://XXX@XXXX:22051
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:01,215 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - doPollDirectory from absolutePath: 20181123, dirName: null
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:01,215 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Polling directory: 20181123
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:01,215 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations] - listFiles(20181123)
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,621 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Found 6 in directory: 20181123
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,621 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=., longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 05:27 ., dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,621 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[.]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,637 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=.., longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 05:27 .., dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,637 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[..]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,637 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=Consolidated, longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 05:26 Consolidated, dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,637 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Polling sub directory: 20181123/Consolidated from: sftp://XXXX:22051/20181123?connectTimeout=90000&disconnect=true&flatten=true&include=.*IMG&knownHostsFile=C%3A%5Cprogram+files%5Cascertain%5CI2R-MystiQ-Engine%5Cknown_hosts&noop=true&password=xxxxxx&preferredAuthentications=password&reconnectDelay=30000&recursive=true&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0%2F5+*+*+*+%3F&separator=Auto&stepwise=false&username=XXXX_ftpuser
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,637 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - doPollDirectory from absolutePath: 20181123/Consolidated, dirName: Consolidated
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,637 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Polling directory: 20181123/Consolidated
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,637 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations] - listFiles(20181123/Consolidated)
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,715 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Found 5 in directory: 20181123/Consolidated
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,715 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=., longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 05:26 ., dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,715 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[Consolidated/.]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,715 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=.., longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 05:27 .., dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,715 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[Consolidated/..]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,715 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=20181124020438943_021420181123INW.MYR, longName=-r-x------ 1 ftpadmin ftpadmin   408097 Nov 23 2018 20181124020438943_021420181123INW.MYR, dir=false]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,731 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[Consolidated/20181124020438943_021420181123INW.MYR]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,731 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=20181124020439099_035820181123INW.MYR, longName=-r-x------ 1 ftpadmin ftpadmin    21689 Nov 23 2018 20181124020439099_035820181123INW.MYR, dir=false]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,731 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[Consolidated/20181124020439099_035820181123INW.MYR]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,731 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=ToPPay, longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 06:41 ToPPay, dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,731 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Polling sub directory: 20181123/Consolidated/ToPPay from: sftp://XXXX:22051/20181123?connectTimeout=90000&disconnect=true&flatten=true&include=.*IMG&knownHostsFile=C%3A%5Cprogram+files%5Cascertain%5CI2R-MystiQ-Engine%5Cknown_hosts&noop=true&password=xxxxxx&preferredAuthentications=password&reconnectDelay=30000&recursive=true&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0%2F5+*+*+*+%3F&separator=Auto&stepwise=false&username=XXXX_ftpuser
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,731 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - doPollDirectory from absolutePath: 20181123/Consolidated/ToPPay, dirName: ToPPay
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,731 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Polling directory: 20181123/Consolidated/ToPPay
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,731 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations] - listFiles(20181123/Consolidated/ToPPay)
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,777 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Found 8 in directory: 20181123/Consolidated/ToPPay
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,777 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=., longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 06:41 ., dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,777 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[Consolidated/ToPPay/.]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,777 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=.., longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 05:26 .., dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,777 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[Consolidated/ToPPay/..]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,793 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=021420181123INW.MYR, longName=-r-x------ 1 ftpadmin ftpadmin   408097 Nov 23 2018 021420181123INW.MYR, dir=false]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,793 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[Consolidated/ToPPay/021420181123INW.MYR]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,793 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=021420181123INW1.MYR, longName=-r-x------ 1 ftpadmin ftpadmin   579829 Nov 23 2018 021420181123INW1.MYR, dir=false]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,793 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[Consolidated/ToPPay/021420181123INW1.MYR]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,793 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=035820181123INW.MYR, longName=-r-x------ 1 ftpadmin ftpadmin    21689 Nov 23 2018 035820181123INW.MYR, dir=false]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,793 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[Consolidated/ToPPay/035820181123INW.MYR]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,793 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=035820181123INW1.MYR, longName=-r-x------ 1 ftpadmin ftpadmin    30954 Nov 23 2018 035820181123INW1.MYR, dir=false]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,793 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[Consolidated/ToPPay/035820181123INW1.MYR]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,809 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=20181124020438943_021420181123INW.MYR, longName=-r-x------ 1 ftpadmin ftpadmin   408097 Nov 23 2018 20181124020438943_021420181123INW.MYR, dir=false]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,809 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[Consolidated/ToPPay/20181124020438943_021420181123INW.MYR]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,809 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=20181124020439099_035820181123INW.MYR, longName=-r-x------ 1 ftpadmin ftpadmin    21689 Nov 23 2018 20181124020439099_035820181123INW.MYR, dir=false]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,809 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[Consolidated/ToPPay/20181124020439099_035820181123INW.MYR]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,809 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=Data, longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 05:26 Data, dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,809 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Polling sub directory: 20181123/Data from: sftp://XXXX:22051/20181123?connectTimeout=90000&disconnect=true&flatten=true&include=.*IMG&knownHostsFile=C%3A%5Cprogram+files%5Cascertain%5CI2R-MystiQ-Engine%5Cknown_hosts&noop=true&password=xxxxxx&preferredAuthentications=password&reconnectDelay=30000&recursive=true&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0%2F5+*+*+*+%3F&separator=Auto&stepwise=false&username=XXXX_ftpuser
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,809 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - doPollDirectory from absolutePath: 20181123/Data, dirName: Data
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,809 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Polling directory: 20181123/Data
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,809 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations] - listFiles(20181123/Data)
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,871 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - Found 501 in directory: 20181123/Data
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,871 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=., longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 05:26 ., dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,871 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[Data/.]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,871 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=.., longName=dr-x------ 2 ftpadmin ftpadmin        0 Mar 12 05:27 .., dir=true]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,871 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[Data/..]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,871 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - SftpFile[fileName=20181123021401015101004323IWNM.MMYR, longName=-r-x------ 1 ftpadmin ftpadmin    14846 Nov 23 2018 20181123021401015101004323IWNM.MMYR, dir=false]
TRACE 2019-04-05T18:40:02,871 [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer] - File did not match. Will skip this file: RemoteFile[Data/20181123021401015101004323IWNM.MMYR]
```

I am sure that the cause of the issue has to be the addition '/' prepending with directory name while listing `listFor(/XXXX)`. How can I avoid it ! .. using `seperator` parameter didn't effect i suppose it is only for producing files and not for consuming. I need to resolve this issue as soon as possible. Please suggest me some solution :(

**EDITED :**

I can reproduce the issue in latest version as well,I suppose the issue is when there is no base path only the '/' gets prepended which should not actually happen

Code Snippet from SftpConsumer.java Camel 3.0.0.M1

```
if (file.isDirectory()) {
                RemoteFile<SftpRemoteFile> remote = asRemoteFile(absolutePath, file, getEndpoint().getCharset());
                if (endpoint.isRecursive() && depth < endpoint.getMaxDepth() && isValidFile(remote, true, files)) {
                    // recursive scan and add the sub files and folders
                    String subDirectory = file.getFilename();
                    String path = absolutePath + "/" + subDirectory;
                    boolean canPollMore = pollSubDirectory(path, subDirectory, fileList, depth);
                    if (!canPollMore) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                // we cannot use file.getAttrs().isLink on Windows, so we dont invoke the method
                // just assuming its a file we should poll
            }
```

> String path = absolutePath + "/" + subDirectory;

Comment: Please show your camel route, especially the uri of your sftp endpoint

Comment: Added the Endpoint URI accordingly ..my routes are dynamically generated. Though I suppose if you go through both traces, you will understand the issue. In my case stepwise is disabled and when particular directory is listed without '/' prefix it can list the directory but camel is prepending the seperator unneccessarily i need a way to stop it

Comment: Try with a newer Camel version, and if its still a problem then log a JIRA

Comment: @ClausIbsen I can reproduce the issue in latest version also. Please find my update in the query area. May I know how I can log a JIRA defect on this ?

Comment: Thanks for checking, the JIRA issue tracker is here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CAMEL/issues

Comment: You can try to fix the code and submit a github PR, or a patch file, or attach the modified .java source to the JIRA ticket. See here how to contribute: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: @ClausIbsen I tried to reproduce the same in my local environment and I fail to reproduce it. In my server, it can still list the folder irrespective of whether it has '/' in front!.  I am not confident in my point, Though I can reproduce the same issue in one of my client environment.

Comment: Yeah its likely harder to reproduce as its likely mostly a FTP server issue, eg what OS and FTP server version/product they use, and also how they have setup the access control of the user you login. However if you have a place you can reproduce it, you can try to modify the source code to avoid the leading slash and see if that fixes it for you.